# Google Drive error on import

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have followed the tutorial provided by Google. But I am experiencing error on the following imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.ContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
```

I have already added Drive API and google_play_services library in my project. And Target SDK is 4.0 compiled with google APIs 4.0. And this is my Manifest. Please help.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googledrivetest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googledrivetest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Comment: have u new play store lib becouse this class added new playstore lib first download new play store lib and use this

Comment: Can you able to post your Logcat error ?

and refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751905/error-implementing-googleapiclient-builder-for-android-development/23752160#23752160 this

Comment: Vaishali This is import problem so how can i run project so how can i see the logcat

Comment: i m also faceing this problem when i was doing on google drive

Comment: Hi Naveen - I think I have the updated google_playstore lib upon checking SDK I have the Rev. 15 of google_play lib.

Comment: Hi Vaishali - I don't have the logcat yet. Since I have to fix these errors first before I can run the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download new playstore Lib Becouse this class added in new playStore Lib

Comment: Hi Naveen - I think I have the updated google_playstore lib upon checking SDK I have the Rev. 15 of google_play lib.

Comment: Not Upgread Your Adt and download new Play Store lib in Android wear Sdk in this U got This Class on Play Store Lib Sorry unable to send u becouse my system has been change outherwise i will send u

Comment: It works! After updating my adt and google play services_lib. Thanks :D