# GoogleDrive Android API not running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api, google-drive-android-api

I have installed all the sdks(s) necessary and the GoogleAPI, Google Play Services etc. but I am still getting an error! Please note I am still in the initial steps of making the application, hence the lack of code, This is my code:

```
package com.example.googleapi;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}
```

This is the compile error I am getting:

```
Error:(38, 17) error: method addConnectionCallbacks in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
required: ConnectionCallbacks
found: MainActivity
reason: actual argument MainActivity cannot be converted to ConnectionCallbacks by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751905/error-implementing-googleapiclient-builder-for-android-development

Comment: @Gerardo I resolved the issue. but, I have different compile errors now..

Comment: @Gerardo this is the issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681019/googledrive-android-api-compile-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` class need to implement following two interfaces: `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`. Also your class now need to implement/Override a couple of methods from those classes. So your `MainActivity` class should looks something similar to following:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
        ,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

For GoogleApiClient visit this link: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient