# Cannot receive callbacks `ConnectionCallbackListener#onConnected` using `GoogleApiClient` in background thread in `Service`

Tags: android, android-service, google-play-services, google-fit

I am having receiving connection callbacks for `GoogleApiClient` in `ConnectionCallbackListener#onConnected()`. As I understand [GoogleApiClient.Builder#setHandler()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#public-methods) determines the `Handler` which will receive these callbacks. If not specified it is on the main thread.

However, I am specifically using a `GcmTaskService` which abstracts the threading for me. This service creates the `GoogleApiClient` whereby I should set the handler. However, I do not know how to get the handler from this service. Any ideas?

Within my custom `GcmTaskService#onRunTask()`:

```
    GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .setHandler(handler)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this);
```

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751905/error-implementing-googleapiclient-builder-for-android-development